# need a read function with timeout to copy file from damaged disk

Tags: c, linux, file, copy, disk

I want to copy a file from CD to my computer but the CD is damaged in certain parts, so about 4-6% of the file is damaged, can not be read. I have tried a lot of file copier programs out there, none helped. When they reach damaged bytes, they take forever to copy. So, I decided to make a file copier suitable for this. For this I need little help:

How to make program read bytes from a file with a timeout? When it takes longer than certain amount time to read a byte it should return null or error of some kind. Any of these platforms will do: Windows, Linux, DOS.

For example, in Linux gcc, in c programming, how to read specific byte from a file with a timeout?

Note: I want to make a program that copies file from damaged CD, and skips unreadable bytes. As, long as it recovers whatever is readable from, I am ok.

Comment: I think this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You shouldn't need to handle timeouts. The OS will handle that. Just do a read, it should fail if the data cannot be read. Have you tried that?

Comment: You need to change that timeout in the kernel SCSI driver. The timeout is not in user-space.